# Reloading JSTL Tag files in Tomcat development mode

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

The application I just inherited defines .tag files - ie JSTL tags written in JSP and other JSTL tags.  Is it possible for Tomcat to pick up on changes to .tag files and recompile/reload them without a restart, in the same manner of "development" mode for JSPs?

**Edit** I should have noted that the context is marked as "reloadable" in Tomcat, and I'm successfully hot-deploying class files and jsps.  It's just not picking up on .tag files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"development" mode for JSPs applies for the tag files too ... unless the tag files are being packaged in a jar file (e.g. in `/META-INF/tags/` of a jar file in `/WEB-INF/lib`).

If the tag files are being deployed like the JSPs (e.g. in `/WEB-INF/tags/`) they will be checked for modification and reloaded on each access if "development" mode is `true`. You shouldn't have to set it explicitly as it's true by default in tomcat 5.5/6.

If you check `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` and "development" isn't explicitly set to `false` but you're still getting issues with reload of .tag files (assuming these aren't jar-packaged) you could try turning off tag pools (for the jasper, `JspServlet`):

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>enablePooling</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

... but this really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I believe this was working the entire time and I was being bitten by some kind of caching in Cygwin of all places :(

Comment: "...unless the tag files are being packaged in a jar file (e.g. in /META-INF/tags/ of a jar file in /WEB-INF/lib)". This answer is 10 years old. Is there by now a way to overcome this restriction? For instance, one could imagine to unzip the JAR files to allow hot reload?

Answer (score 0):

Libraries/files in classpath won't be hotdeployed/hotloaded in Tomcat. As far as I know, Glassfish v3 is the only who can do that. Tomcat can only hotdeploy changes in JSP files and Java source files. However, since Tomcat is a pretty quick (re)starter (done in less than 3 seconds in contrary to around 30 seconds for Glassfish), manually restarting shouldn't be a major issue, is it? A hotdeploy itself would already take about the same time.